# For every word in word list create a file containing the matches

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, grep

Suppose there is a file `details` which has a list of words like `adobe`,`cards` etc... say 1000 words are there in that file .
In the same directory there are multiple files say 2000 files.

Now what I need is the shell script to capture which words from the file `details` is used in which file and then write it into another file like:

```
adobe-file1
cards-0(i.e not used any where) 
state-file1,file2
```

Answer (score 4):

For every word in the file `detail` create a file with an extension `.r` that contains any filenames where the word was found:

```
grep -rowf detail --exclude=detail | sort -t: -k2 | awk -F: '{print $1>($2".r")}'
```

Comment: might be helpful to use `-o` as well